# select pg_database_size('name') hangs and can't be killed

Tags: postgresql

Our PostgreSQL 10.1 server ran out of connections today because a monitor process that was calling

```
select pg_database_size('databasename');
```

was getting stuck.  It was NOT getting an obvious Lock.  It just never returned.  The monitor dutifully logged in every few minutes, over and over until we ran out of connections.  When I run the query for other databases it works, but not for our main database.

Killing the calling process did not clear the query.

```
select pg_cancel_backend(1234)
```

doesn't kill the query.  Nor does

```
select pg_terminate_backend(1234)
```

Ditto if I run the query by hand, nothing kills it in the database.

I will probably have to restart the database server to recover from this.  However I'd like to prevent it from happening again.

What is this function doing that would resist signals and never return (like 8 hours after being invoked)?   Is there any way to clear them from the process table without restarting the database and breaking the users who still have the few remaining connections still active in the system?

Comment: I waited a few more hours for things to recover.  Even this doesn't work:  $  pg_ctl stop -m immediate
waiting for server to shut down............................................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down

Comment: That sounds like you are having trouble with your storage system and processes are going into uninterruptible sleep trying to access it. Assuming you are on UNIX, what does `ps -f` show for these processes? Can you [get a stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend) from the stuck backend?

Comment: I think that is what happened.   I'm in a Google Cloud VM.  Something must have happened to the underlying storage that broke everything.  II was watching the console when I tried to reboot it and it looked like it was timing out trying to release the storage as it tried to shut down.  There was nothing obvious in kern.log or on the system.  If it happens again I'll see if I can get more diagnostics before pushing the reset button.  Thanks for the feedback!  Confirms my suspicions.